# Looking for a DM solution to a Squishy group

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, equipment, encounter-design, new-players

I've been playing tabletop RPGs for a while off and on, only a little as a DM, but I get the basics of it. I've convinced some of my immediate and extended family (most of whom are NOT gamers, let alone tabletop gamers) to play. They've all created their characters and seem really excited about their classes, but the group is over... squishy. Two druids, a bard, a wizard and a warlock. We have a monk, but I doubt he'll be available a lot since he's an out-of-town student.

I'm giving them their first campaign as a group in the next couple weeks, and I'm trying to think about an edge I can give to them in their first or second encounter that will help make up for the fact that they're so squishy. Something that's not too advanced that will always give them the edge, but something that gives them a chance. I know I can do that with fudging die rolls, but I'd almost rather make it something that *they* do instead of me, like remembering to active the magic item that they found last time or something.

So there is a definitive reason why front-liner classes (Paladin, Barbarian, etc) make good front liners -- because they can absorb damage. For a group consisting mainly of folks who are not able to absorb most damage, what should I focus on boosting with this group? Is it *only* AC that I should worry about, or are there other factors?

Comment: What sort of campaign are you running? A dungeon crawl with lots of combat, wilderness survival, political intrigue with mostly social encounters? How bad their squishiness impacts them will highly depend on this

Comment: Also are you only interested in magic items to give them or consider other solutions viable too?

Comment: What level are the PCs?

Comment: They are all brand new to the game, level 1. I thought about starting them at 2, but there are so many new skills and choices to make, and I can tell they were already starting to get overwhelmed, so I wanted to give them the chance to have fun to make the extra choices worthwhile.  We did have a basic "how stuff works" session during the creation, lots of questions and how mechanics like proficiency works, etc.

Comment: We’ve attracted several unsupported answers so far, and it may be because you’ve framed it as a “what are some magic items?” question. Instead, I suggest reframing it as just describing your problem and asking how it can be solved, rather than describing your problem and asking for magic item ideas. For now I’ve voted to close as “opinion based”.

Comment: Can you tell us the encounter you gave them? How many of what monster(s)?

Comment: We're starting with the level 1 part of Princes of the Apocalypse, the Trouble in Red Larch area - the Necromancer's Tomb and the Bandit/Bear encounter. That should get them to 3, and we can start the normal Princes line of campaign.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The party suffers from first-level-itis

It is a common problem that all 1st-level adventures suffer from; starter equipment, low hp, swinginess of the dice. It's all out to get you.

The make up of your party isn't too bad. The wizard, warlock, and bard all should have some sort of protection spell(s) available. Bards, warlocks, and druids all can wear at least light armor. The monk has their own defense abilities. And in one level, the druids will have wild shape which gives them a chunk of extra hp to keep them up and running. All in all, they are not in a bad place. Just need some starting help.

### There are a few ways you can resolve this

Damage is inevitable, so it's up to you as the DM to decide how to give the players, AND YOU, the best experience while keeping everyone alive.

#### Level up

The simplest course of action is, don't start at 1st level. This is the most common solution, and I know a lot of campaigns that automatically start at level two or three. Depending on how high you start, some or all of the characters will have reached the point where they can select an archetype and have enough hp to handle more than a fly bumping into them. If I'm creating a campaign with a group that has previous D&D experience, I will usually start at level three.

There is a down side, and it shows up more often with new players; they don't know how their character works. By making the characters higher level, they may be overwhelmed with options. My current group, consisting mostly of long-time players, will sometimes have one-offs where we start at level 5, 10, or even 15. But because we didn't "grow" with the character, there is always a lot of confusion about what abilities are available, synergies, how features works, etc. So suddenly making them 3rd-level means they won't have any experience in how their character operates. Meaning you solved some squishiness, but added complexity. That's why this works best for experienced players.

#### Benefactors

Your party could be sponsored by an individual, or by a guild, who will back their adventures. Tasha's Cauldron of Everything has a [whole chapter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/group-patrons) on "Group Patrons". All of its example patrons include a section on perks and what they can offer. Some of the items listed are:

- divine services
- equipment
- money
- research
- sanctuary
- training

This has ups and downs depending on how much or how little help you provide the players.

I prefer supplying better equipment than the starter set allows. Instead of leather armor, characters get studded leather. The druids can get scale armor made from alligators so it's non-metal. The wizard has a couple extra ritual spell scrolls to add to their spellbook.

If you know the starting adventure(s) will have an outdoor aspect, the patron can teach proficiency to *Nature* and *Survival* if no one has it. Similarly, if there will be a number of traps and locks, have the patron supply thieves tools and train someone in their use if there is no rogue in the party. These are skills that will have immediate impact, and may even become a defining trait later in their career.

#### Magic items

This is the step-brother to benefactors. Not only does the benefactor give stuff, but they give magic stuff too! It could just be a few extra potions of healing, all the way up to magical weapons and armor. I will warn you from experience that giving high level magic may make them over powerful and it takes away some of the challenge and triumph. Now, I err on the side of caution by using lower end magic items and consumables like potions of healing that get may restocked as needed.

I recall that for one "season" of Adventure League, it was okay to start out with one non-weapon, non-armor, Common rarity magic item when you created a 1st-level character. Some of the items are just for show, but maybe that Clockwork Amulet or the Ruby of the War Mage will be just the thing to help the party make the most of their adventure?

And you are not limited to the magic items found in the DMG. Feel free to create your own. I've invented a few based on the specific party make up, but here are a few "generic" items that may inspire you:

- Potion of spell slots: Drinking this potions gives the drinker one additional 1st-level spell slot if the class gives the character spell slots (so your druid, bard, wizard). Only works once per 24 hour period.
- Ring of close calls: (requires attunement) The wearer of this ring, if brought to 0 hp, will automatically stabilize on their next turn prior to making a death saving throw. On the following turn, if still at 0 hp, they will regain 1 hp. Once the ring is used to regain a hit point, it will not work again for one week.
- Cloak of embroidered adamantine: This fashionable cloak has threads of adamantine woven throughout the design. If the wearer it struck with a critical hit, the cloak will absorb the extra damage making it a normal hit. However, after the first hit, the cloak tears making it unmendable and no longer protects the wearer from critical hits.

Create simple things that, will have high impact (as far as defense goes) for lower level character, but will lose some of its luster as they gain levels. For instance, the potions and the cloak are one time use only, so eventually they will dry up. And while the ring may have value in later levels for the free hp, like it's cousin the Periapt of Wound Closure it requires an attunement slot which becomes more and more precious as they adventure and find more magic. Also, if external healing isn't administered by the character's second turn, they lose that safety net for a week.

#### Alternate method of enemy damage

It may work for you, I've only tried it for one session so I can't say how well it will work in the long run. In fact, I would recommend stopping after everyone is level 2, level 3 at the maximum.

Basically, instead of rolling for damage it was always a fixed value. So daggers, arrows, claw attacks, and other small weapons always do 1 hp damage. Longswords, battleaxes, and bites do 2 hp, and larger weapons would do 3 hp. Spells and traps would work as if you rolled 1's for any dice (So each *magic missile* dart did 1 + 1 points of damage). You get the idea; the damage isn't always minimum, but close to it.

It helped in that even with the occasional critical hit (flat double damage), the damage never got too big. It also helped in keeping math simple. As a suggestion, write down what damage everything does ahead of time.

But something like this would not be sustainable for a whole campaign. It greatly favors the players and it may make the first "final boss" encounter seem a little anticlimactic. I would also tell the group up front about this rule, and give it an absolute cut-off point.

### Tried and failed

Here are a few things I've tried, but didn't work out well in the end:

- Magic weapons and armor with plus bonuses

  - This sounds good, but because of bounded accuracy, they became too powerful and there wasn't any real thrill to combat. However things like the Moon-Touched Sword with no bonuses work well.
- A tank escort

  - They become a crutch to the real players. Everyone just hung back and let the tank (who only dodged) get swung at. And then it became, "Well why don't they attack? They're a fighter, so they should fight too." So not only did they want someone to take all the blows, they wanted them to also take care of anyone more powerful than a goblin.
- A creature escort

  - Unlike the tank, adding a creature (a mastiff, a bear, a panther, etc) the party went out of their way to protect the creature endangering themselves more than if the creature wasn't there.
- Chime of Opening

  - It's rare for a reason. They ended up not using it very often (preferred to kick in doors, etc) so they had this automatic garage door opener to break into strongholds, open trapped chests from 60ft away, etc well beyond their 1st- and 2nd-level.

### There is more to life than combat

Remember, there are [three pillars](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/introduction#TheThreePillarsofAdventure) to adventuring, not just one:

1. Exploration
2. Social Interaction
3. Combat

Focus your first level of the group around the other two pillars. **You know the strengths and weaknesses of the group, so tailor an in-or-near-town adventure** to start them off. There are always mysteries to solve in the community: a lost pet/child, strange sightings in the graveyard, a curse to be lifted. And townfolk full of rumors and backstory to make the community have depth. But you don't have to leave out combat.

There is an advantage of having combat close to home; townfolk to come to the rescue. For instance, my party confronted the local bandits that were extorting the town for money and supplies. I didn't plan for it, but it just worked out where a few bad rolls on the characters part and a few good rolls on the bandits and the whole party was downed at high noon. But instead of finishing off the party, the bandits gloated and rode away saying next time it's double. So I had the townfolk swoop in and revive everyone. Now the party had three days to come up with a better plan to take on the bandits. With teamwork, better strategy, utilizing the townfolk, and some dumb luck, they won the next encounter.

### In the end

You shouldn't need to cheat or fudge; everyone just needs a push to get over the short hurdle of first-level-itis. Then your party will be strong enough to take on some real action.

Comment: To give some feedback on my downvote (and probably the other downvotes), this is exactly the sort of answer [our citation expectations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8697/62294) say we we *are not* looking for. The question presents a problem, and your answer appears to just be a list of ideas that look look like they *could* work. We don't want your "try this" ideas. We want tested solutions that you know work, and an explanation of how they can be implemented based on how you have successfully implemented them in the past.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov, thanks for the comment. I've revamped the whole thing to be from the perspective of what I've tried, including tried and failed. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tremendous improvement, I've changed to an upvote.

Comment: Discussing encounter design may also be very beneficial here. Not every encounter has to be risky/deadly - some can be quick and fun to show the power of the PCs! Although I do trend to like the risky/deadly - both as an [experienced] player and DM.

Comment: @NautArch, I added a section on the three pillars and mentioned tailoring a starting encounter.

Answer (score 3):

Well, if all you're looking for is to give them a little more survivability in combat, you could give them each a *potion of heroism* or even a *potion of invulnerability* as a starting gift. But I'm going to assume that's not the band-aid answer you're looking for. So, with that said...

#### Build the adventure with your players' characters in mind.

Though not explicitly stated, I'm going to assume your PCs are all 1st level. 1st-level adventures are tricky to get right because of a number of factors, but in general, the PCs are not prepared or equipped for the danger that awaits them.

People often forget that the *Player's Handbook* outright describes characters below 5th level as apprentices in their respective classes.

> In the **first tier** (levels 1–4), characters are effectively apprentice adventurers. They are learning the features that define them as members of particular classes, including the major choices that flavor their class features as they advance (such as a wizard’s Arcane Tradition or a fighter’s Martial Archetype). The threats they face are relatively minor, usually posing a danger to local farmsteads or villages.

They are novices in training to become those classes. So, you don't have a party of two druids, a bard, a wizard, and a warlock—you have a party of 5 apprentices in those classes. They should, therefore, be sent on apprentice-level appropriate adventures. I'll tell you what I mean.

My go-to adventure that I run for fresh-faced 1st-level parties is a glorified fetch quest. It goes something like this:

The PCs show up in Phandalin (yes, the same small mining town from *Lost Mine of Phandelver* and *Dragon of Icespire Peak*), explicitly because nobody would hire them in a bigger city like Waterdeep or Neverwinter. *"Whenever you responded to a quest on a job board, the quest-giver would ask for your adventuring resumes and/or references, of which you have none."* Everyone laughs at this because it is relatable humour to anyone who's tried to get a job with little experience in the field, but it also explicitly sends a message that they aren't yet ready for all the ***Dungeons & Dragons™*** that the game has waiting for them.

Then I tell them there is a dragon in the region causing all kinds of trouble (maybe a green dragon if I think *Lost Mine of Phandelver* would be a good follow-up adventure for this group, or a white dragon if I'd rather run *Dragon of Icespire Peak* next), and the locals who don't know the difference between a 1st-level adventuring apprentice and a 5th-level fighter might even ask them if they have come to Phandalin to deal with it, but before they get any delusions of grandeur, a wizard appears who dismisses the idea of slaying a dragon as foolishly suicidal. Instead, he offers them a job that's more their speed: recover his lost spellbook which he dropped running from the very dragon in question the previous day.

Then they must walk up the road to where he dropped it, find the spellbook has been claimed by goblins, and have to fight or negotiate to get it back. The goblins are not particularly organized, and just about any attempt to sneak up on them will catch them with their pants down. Usually, I use four goblins, but they are split into two groups; three are obsessing over their stolen loot, and one has been forced to stand guard outside their cave (a fate he doesn't enjoy and slacks off about). Sometimes, players rush in foolishly, in which case the guard runs to rejoin his friends and they have to fight four goblins. Usually, though, parties will either sneak up on and knock out the guard without a fight or even befriend the guard who doesn't much like his fellow goblin allies because they always pick on him, allowing them in both cases to ambush the other three. Occasionally, they'll even negotiate with the goblins and trade gold for the spellbook (that the goblins can't read anyway). In virtually all cases though, the party walks away with the spellbook and no casualties, because 4 goblins aren't particularly challenging. On the way back to town, I always scare the players with a sighting of the dragon, but he doesn't bother with them and flies off with a goat in his clutches. Then they return with the spellbook, the wizard pays them in gold, and I tell them they all level up.

You might think this doesn't sound all that fun compared to delving into intricate dungeons and fighting epic dragons, but I assure you, I've run this many times, and the opportunities for an enjoyable adventure are many. Have fun roleplaying with locals, portraying the differences between the way a farmer looks at them as potential dragon slayers and a wizard who knows them to be little more than a hired gopher; play up the humour of a bullied goblin guard who resents the other goblins he is supposed to be watching out for; encourage creative problem solving by telling your players directly that they can approach the goblin cave in a variety of ways, using stealth, negotiation, or sword & sorcery to get what they came for. You do all of this and you will make a simple—but appropriate—1st-level fetch-quest seem like so much more.

And then, by the time they are finished, they'll be ready for something a little more adventuresome. Maybe I'll transition into one of the two Phandalin adventures I mentioned previously, or maybe I'll transition into something else entirely. Either way, I can be confident they are ready for it because I'll know that they have already survived their first taste of adventure.

Now, I'm not suggesting you use my adventure. The point of sharing it is to put you in the right mindset that your PCs aren't ready for the big adventures that you might be wanting to send them on. "How do I make sure they survive the dangers I'm planning to throw at them?" Well, you don't throw those dangers at them! Come up with something that is appropriately low-stakes to match their low level, and you should be fine!

Or, you can always level them up and start at level 2 or 3. That's an option too.

Answer (score -1):

## Use terrain, and melee-only enemies

*(This worked quite well for us, when we had a similar setup. The downside is that you have to prepare a lot more than for a usual party and for the ~5 levels cannot use premade adventures)*

Every one of them (except the Monk, but you do not expect him to be there a lot) should have good ranged options.

- A very hungry bear attacks when they are in a cabin in the woods. They know it will tear the walls down eventually, but they have a few rounds to shoot at it through the window
- Zombies attack them in the desert, the lose sand difficult terrain
- They run into some Grey Oozes in a wide open area, so they can run and shoot
- Worgs attack them in the woods, luckily the trees are easy to climb

The point is, there are many enemies they can easily beat in favorable terrain. Doing this at the first few levels has two benefits:

1. You get good practice in creating useful for encounters (I find these more interesting than plain fields anyway)
2. As they level up, you can *gradually* introduce enemies with some ranged options (and less favorable terrain):

   - Bugbears do less than half damage at range
   - Probably only half of the skeletons carry bows

By the time they get jumped by 6 Cloakers in a small room, they will be tactically prepared, and know their characters.

Comment: @NautArch, yes, I should have added that this is from actual experience. Edited

Answer (score -2):

Here are a few options to help them out. These are based on my experience with a low level group (level 1-2) of few characters, who therefore were vulnerable to typical encounters in published adventures.

- ***Potion of Healing***. Probably the best, in terms of modest magic items. Its commonly available, as a consumable self-limiting, but most importantly, can be used after the fact, so they do not have to burn it on speculating its needed. Items that need to be used in advance have a risk of never being used, as the party is waiting "for the right time".
- **Mastiff**. Not a magic item, but works well with a druid heavy group, which probably has affinity for animals already. They provide a hit point buffer in combat, soak up attacks, can even meaningfully attack early on, and with only 5 hp, will eventually outlive their usefulness.
  They also help keep watch against surprises. My group even has developed some emotional attachment to their dog for it valiantly saving their hides more than once in a close battle.
- **Favors of friends**. For example, there may be a friendly church or temple, that will provide a raise dead once in advance for a promise of future services. This provides a safety layer, should someone actually die as long as it is not a TPK, also works after the fact, and even allows you to act as a plot hook for further action. One if the characters in the group was infested with brain maggots, and had no way to avoid certain death. They took to the allied temple, got the character's head cut open and the maggot removed — which killed the character, but he swiftly got *revivified*. In exchange, they took up a mission for their temple, which is the current adventure we are playing.
- **Hirelings**. This is the classic way to bolster a squishy, low level group, going all the way back to 1st edition. They can hire a guard or other NPC fighter to accompany them and frontline. They likely will have to pay more than just the recommended 2gp/day from the PHB, considering this is a lot more dangerous than just normal guard duty, and, as an NPC, is also a bit more work for you. But it at the same time can give you a way to have someone around to make a suggestion should they get stuck. Just keep in mind to not make it stronger than the PCs and keep it simple, to keep the spotlight on them. My group has been using this too, to great effect bolstering their strength, by hiring an elven fighter and paying him with a smaller share of the spoils.

All these methods have worked well for us in play. We used healing potions, hirelings and mastiffs even with a higher level group (level 5) that was light on healing, for example we hired a few men-of-arms and a ballista to help in a fight against a young dragon. At higher levels, they become too weak to meaningfully contribute and die too easily, but in tier one they can be of great help.

Comment: To give some feedback on my downvote (and probably the other downvotes), this is exactly the sort of answer [our citation expectations](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8697/62294) say we we *are not* looking for. The question presents a problem, and your answer appears to just be a list of ideas that look look like they *could* work. We don't want your "try this" ideas. We want tested solutions that you know work, and an explanation of how they can be implemented based on how you have successfully implemented them in the past.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Thanks, I was wondering where these DVs came from, I had not expected them. My low level group have used multiple of these techniques to great effect (revive, dogs, hirelings, and of course healing potions). I can spruce up the suggestions with such anecdotes, although in my experience, this won't affect most of the DVs, as few people re-read an answer to a question they already voted on.

Comment: But a better answer is less likely to attract further downvotes, and improving an answer should be a fulfilling end in itself.

Comment: How do first level characters afford hirelings? And doesn’t the introduction of more NPC’s mean shared XP and longer delay until level up?

Comment: @Nautarch: 1. they have a loot sharing arrangement, its in the answer. 2. per PHB, a hireling only costs 2gp/day even for an "expert" like a guard you can afford that even with starting gold (also in the answer) 3. They also found some gold during their first adventure

Answer (score -3):

### Have the enemies do less damage.

As the DM, it is your job to tell a good story.  It is hard to tell a good story if all the protagonists are dead.  If they die in an organic way, due to bad decisions, bad luck, that's fine.  The risk of real failure makes the successes all the sweeter.  But if they die because you set up a fight they cannot win, if you could very really have said 'rocks fall, you die' and it would have been roughly the same outcome, then that's bad DMing.

You can, should, and in many cases *must* balance encounters such that the outcome is at least in doubt.  In 5e D&D it is very possible for players to end up with characters that are weaker than the norm, or unable to take on typical encounters aimed at characters of their level - this is very common with players that don't have the background in the kind of games that encourage tactical thinking and minmaxing.  It's also quite possible to end up with characters that are much stronger than the norm, or players who are skilled at tactical thinking and vastly outperform the expected.  In either of these situations, you need to modify combat encounters to accommodate the unexpected.

One of the simplest changes you can make is to lower enemy damage.  Lowering it by 1/3rd, or by half, will result in longer combats that will give players time to get a handle on their options, their spells, potential tactics, and other facets of the game that will slowly allow you to ramp up enemy damage without outright killing them.  This is **especially important** at level 1, as D&D 5e gives players hp by level while keeping other bonuses (weapon damage, to-hit) largely static - so player death at levels 1 and 2 is far, far more likely.

There are other solutions, giving the players friendly npcs who take hits and help them, giving them advice while making characters, handing out free hp or other bonuses, but they all have drawbacks.  Friendly npcs take screen time where no player is getting to take actions, 'advice' in character design takes away from the joy of creating your own thing, free hp or things not covered by the existing rules lead to suspicion (people trust big bound book o' rules but not google doc, even if google doc is superior).  Modifying monster stats and encounter design allows you to solve the problem 'behind the screen' - if done right, the players should not be aware of any changes, and can simply enjoy the game.

**nb**:  There are techniques other than the ones I listed, like avoiding combat, and they are quite extensive and often fairly involved.  I've omitted listing them all out because I think out of them all, for this kind of situation, simply altering monster stats/encounter design is the best solution.  But people have been butting their heads against this kind of problem for decades, and there are quite a lot of solutions out there (and variations on those solutions) that they have developed.

(It's just that putting them all in this answer would turn it into a novel)

Answer (score -5):

Firstly, I'd advise not focusing on "metal armor" so much, but looking at the party members' ACs. A well-built character can have a surprisingly high AC without (metal) armor (eg., a tortle starts with an AC of 17!).

And, secondly: I would 100% support making the edge something that the players can invoke rather than fudging die rolls. Potions of healing are often go-to options for this, and an option that a lot of people new to D&D will understand from video games and general pop culture. As a small word of caution: if you don't want potions to be too common in your world, make sure that's clear both in-game and out-of-game.

The cloak of protection is an uncommon (attunement) magical item that provides a +1 bonus to AC (and saves!). It's probably the easiest way to bump somebody's AC, but it's a static bonus rather than something the players can choose to use (at least, after choosing who gets one). It's also something that - IMO - is better used as a reward than handed out before the quest. Much the same can be said about +1 armor, too.

Depending on the campaign, there may be some world-building options that are unique to your world, too. If the players are Chosen of the Gods, perhaps they each get one "get out of death free" card (possibly per level?) to represent the influence of the gods in their life.

Beyond the single-encounter level, making sure that the players know when they've come to a safe place to take a short/long rest is an invaluable aid to the players. You could aid that along by giving the wizard *alarm* for their spellbook, so they can ritually-cast it before the party takes a rest.

Personally, this GM would lean heavily towards starting each PC out with a potion of healing. I've both run and played in campaigns in which PCs started out with one: they're a *great* security blanket for the players without being too powerful, and they help teach D&D's resource management game without being too costly if they're mismanaged.

Comment: I like the idea of potions -- I'd like something that could potentially be passed around between the players, or maybe cast on various players who may need it more at any given time --- the cloak is a bit much, and only one character would benefit from it.  Thanks for the tip - I'll add that to the list! (Oh and the gift of an alarm scroll is a great idea too!)

Comment: Regarding your first sentence, it’s really only gets harder to kill PCs around 4th or 5th level, at 3rd level and below, it’s remarkably easy to accidentally TPK or have to pull punches, adjust ACs or hit points, or fudge rolls to not TPK.

Comment: I've had cases where monsters get like 2-3 nat 20's in a row (or in a single fight) and oof... not great when you've got a 10hp Cleric or an 8hp Wizard or something... I'd agree with @ThomasMarkov

Comment: @ThomasMarkov:  I'll adjust that first bit to reflect a wider experience pool.

Comment: -1.  I disagree with the suggestions in the answer.  They are destructive to suspension of disbelief, and are often used as _examples_ of bad DMing.